# Coolant and water in oil problem

Tags: engine, vauxhall, astra

I have an 06 Vauxhall Astra and it overheated so I filled with antifreeze, 5 miles later it had gone, over last day have been topping up with water and watching when stationary and when driving and the water just disappears and smoke from under bonnet, got home after 5 min drive water gone and now I have the sludge on oil cap, have looked best I can for leaks but can't find anything obvious, do I need to add oil if it's watery, any advice on what it is would be grateful

Comment: What does the oil look like on the dipstick? Also could you use full sentences with punctuation and not one long run on with comas.

Answer (score 1):

A leak should be pretty obvious if the car is using that much coolant. As you say the oil is watery though then I suspect the cylinder head gasket has blown. This will need attention & replacing asap.